# Is it possible to sort an array in php to get the given output?

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array.

```
$arr = array('10min', '25min', '35 min', '1 hour', '10-20min', '2 hours', '25-30min', '2-2 1/2 hours', '45min' );
```

I need the output in the following order.
10min
10-20min
25min
25-30min
35min
45min
1hour
2hours
2-2 1/2 hours
Is it possible to get in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's almost definitely possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: One way is to recreate the array with your order.

Comment: I tried to separate values with 'hours' to a new array. And then values having '-'(hyphen) to a different array and then the remaining to another one. But couldn't achieve it.

Comment: @Mihai: But I get the values from different tables in Mysql. The same function is used to get different info from db. So it is impossible to use ORDER BY.

Comment: It may be better to post that code you tried, using different arrays for different suffixes here, so one can see what went wrong ? (Can't write that function for you right now, have to step out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this code :)

```
<?php

        $arr = array('10min', '25min', '35 min', '1 hour', '10-20min', '2 hours', '25-30min', '2-2 1/2 hours', '45min');
        $m = [];
        $h = [];

        foreach ($arr as $a) {
            if (strpos($a,"min")) $m[] = $a;
            elseif(strpos($a,"hours") || strpos($a,"hour")) $h[] = $a;
        }

        foreach ($m as &$mm) $mm = str_replace("-","zzz",$mm);
        foreach ($h as &$hh) $hh = str_replace("-","zzz",$hh);

        natsort($m);
        natsort($h);

        foreach ($m as &$mm) $mm = str_replace("zzz","-",$mm);
        foreach ($h as &$hh) $hh = str_replace("zzz","-",$hh);

        $a = array_merge($m,$h);
        print_r($a);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array('10min', '25min', '35 min', '1 hour', '10-20min', '2 hours', '25-30min', '2-2 1/2 hours', '45min' );
echo $arr['0'], "<br>";
echo $arr['4'], "<br>";
echo $arr['1'], "<br>";
echo $arr['6'], "<br>";
echo $arr['8'], "<br>";
echo $arr['3'], "<br>";
echo $arr['5'], "<br>";
echo $arr['7'], "<br>";
?>
```

If that's particulary what you want to do, then here you go, if you asked for something like that as an example..
        use `foreach()`

Comment: Even if I use conditions to echo inside a foreach() it is gonna give me the same result right? It will not sort the array.

Comment: Can you give me the template of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Template? What kind of template?

Comment: a real example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: List of foods are available. They can be filtered using different ways. One of them is the time taken make the food. So once the time taken button is clicked, a dropdown containing the sorted array will pop up.

Comment: Why not making all in minutes, then convert minutes to time(hours,mins,sec)?

Comment: The values were inserted in the db manually. It is nearly impossible to back and change all the hours to mins. Any other idea?